# In ASP.Net, what is the best way to understand and analyze performance?

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, performance

Until now, I have not create any massive applications using ASP.Net.  However, I am looking to create an application that has the potential to be very performance intensive. So I am looking for some tools or best practices when it comes to performance.  I would like to be able to know how to:

1. See my current performance (good or bad)
2. View items that need fixing
3. And being able to compare two performance variable items would be great as well.

For any of you expert .Net Devs out there, I would really appreciate some help.  I am not looking for anyone to solve my problems - but I am looking for people to help me get pointed in the right direction.  Links to the best articles on this stuff or personal advice would be great.

Thanks in advance,
Gabriel

Comment: You may use StyleCop http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3846906/c-analyze-unsafe-method-invokes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are talking about performance, do you mean client side (JavaScript) performance or web server performance (load testing)?

If you're talking about JavaScript performance, test on really slow machines, using various browsers and various operating systems.  I'm not sure if there are any tools available that will test this for you, given the differences in platforms, javascript engines, and the effect of an old machine.

If you mean server performance, then you want to get a couple of things:

- [A load testing tool](http://www.webresourcesdepot.com/15-free-functionality-and-load-testing-tools-for-web-applications/)
- [ANTS Performance Profiler](http://www.red-gate.com/products/ants_performance_profiler/index.htm)

ANTS will show you portions of your code that are the bottlenecks, and show you timelines for the entire page load process (database wait times as well).

Comment: I guess I was leaning more towards the server side performance.  I have heard about ANTS before. It's really that good huh?  I will have to check that out.

Comment: Yeah.  The tool is really great.  Easy to use, without a lot of setup, and it provides a lot of information.

Comment: I just came across this post and thought it might be of use (titled: Free .NET Profilers and Some Paid Ones Too): http://www.devcurry.com/2009/11/free-net-profilers-and-some-paid-ones.html

Answer (score 2):

This is a big subject and there many areas to cover, client side, browser performance, server side, scalability.

One place I'd suggest starting with is end-user perception, really what is good or bad will be decided by your users.  For example, if your site takes a few seconds to process something, just displaying instant feedback (such as an animated GIF) instead of a full page post back can make the world of difference to the user exeperience.

I would wholeheartedly recommend the APress book "Ultra-fast ASP.NET" it is filled with many little gems to guide you through all of the issues you mention (worth the buy even if you're not using SQL server).

Comment: +1 for this book recommendation - just got it and it is great :-)

Comment: awesome!  I will definitely pick that up!