# C#: Analyze "unsafe" method invokes

Tags: c#, exception, methods, call

How (actual with which instuments like ReSharper) in VS10 developer can find "unsafe" method invokes - i.e. invokes, which unattainable by call stack in no one safe block (try-catch) ?

```
class A
{
    public static vois f()
    {
        try
        {
            ... 
            B.DoSome(); // safe call, exceptions handled
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            ...
        }
    }

    public static void f2()
    {
        ... //no try-catch block
        B.DoSome(); // possible unhandled exception
    }
}

class B
{
    public static void DoSome()
    {
        ...
        //no try-catch block, possible to raise unhandled exception
    }
}
```

Comment: Very vague, "which unattainable by call stack" makes little sense.  Are you talking about P/Invoke?

Comment: Could you rephrase so we all understand what you mean?

Comment: I try to explain problem in source: http://snipplr.com/view/41372/c-analyze-unsafe-method-invokes/

Comment: Hans Passant: no, in this scope i don't mean P/Invoke, only CLR calls.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you would like to make sure your application is not crashing due to an unhandled exception, this can be easily done by subscribing to the [`UnhandledException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception.aspx) event of the `AppDomain`.

Note: Please **[don't put a try-catch in every method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/416616/parsing-c-finding-methods-and-putting-try-catch-to-all-methods/416624#416624)** as your sample suggests.

Comment: +1 for the warning.  The illusion of safety is worse than mere lack of safety, as at least in the latter case, you are aware of the threat.

Comment: Thanks a lot, so now I think what good way is catching UnhandledException of AppDomain. It's good way?

Comment: @Jamon, AppDomain.UnhandledException gives you a chance to take some final action (such as logging or displaying a message box to the user) before the application shuts down.  It does not give you a way to prevent the application from shutting down.  It's important to have as a final catch (mainly for logging), but any exceptions you expect and know how to handle, you'll want to handle explicitly at the point where it can be thrown.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is quite vague, but perhaps [Exception Hunter](http://www.red-gate.com/products/Exception_Hunter/) is what you're after?

Comment: Yeah, on first look it like what I want:) Thanks. But, do you know free analogues of this stuff?)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a great microsoft tool http://stylecop.codeplex.com/.